# Fit sum of exponentials

Tags: algorithms, exponential-function

I am looking for an algorithm that fits a sum of exponential. for example I have something like this: $$y(x)=ae^{−bx}+c+de^{-fx}+h$$ and I want to find a,b,c,d,f and h values. Of this sum I have only the x and y values that belong to the curve represented by the previous model. Is there any paper that explains that?

Comment: For a start, you should combine $c$ and $h$ into a single additive constant; you can't determine them separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A direct method of fitting (no initial guess, no iteration) for the function :
$$y(x)=a+be^{px}+ce^{qx}$$
is summarized below (parameters to be computed : $a,b,c,p,q$ ). It works as well in case of negative $p, q$ :
[image]

Instead of minimizing the absolute deviations, the variant below minimizes the relatives deviations :

[image]

The theory of this method is given in the paper :https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales (in French).

The method for the function 
$$y(x)=a+be^{px}+ce^{qx}+de^{rx}$$
is also available, but not published yet. Contact the author if interrested.

Comment: Hello @JJacquelin. I would be interested in seeing your tri-exponential regression result. I tried to follow your paper, to implement my own, but I'm getting stuck with all imaginary solutions to p, q, r. Have you by any chanced published it in the interim?

Comment: The integral equation I came up with was: $y = A(SSS)+B(-SS)+C(S)+Dx^2+Ex+F$ where $S$* refers to the number of integrations. This lead me to solve the equations $A=p q r, B=qr+pr+pq, C=p+q+r$.

Comment: @ wdkrnls : Your calculus is correct. Well done ! So, the linear regression leads to approximates of $A,B,C,D,E,F$. Solving the cubic polynomial equation for $p,q,r$ should give the three real roots. But if the scatter on the data is too large and/or if the number of points is not large enough, the numerical calculus fails. Number of points and scatter are very critical factors because the successive numerical integrations are likely to introduce too much deviations.

Comment: @JJacquelin  Hi.  Did you publish an explicit solution for the 3 exponent case?  And have you posted any implementations?   Thank you.   Will cite your work when we publish, of course.

Comment: @DrM. Thank you for your interest. It isn't very difficult to extend the theory of the two exponent case to the three exponent case. See above the comment from wdkrnls.  The three exponent case is not published yet. I left unfinished the study of numerical examples. It appear that the three successive numerical integrations introduces  large deviation especially in case of scattered data. They are seven parameters in the function to be fitted which is a big chalenge for numerical computation whatever the method of regression is. I prefer study more promising problems for concrete applications.

Comment: @JJacquelin, thank you, that makes sense.  The bi-exponent case is still fantastically useful.

Comment: Meanwhile I have a look at this old study. In fact the fitting is not bad if the data is not too much scattered. The systematic study of practical use is far to be completed. Nevertheless tomorow I will post on the forum some information and one of the numerical example.

Comment: I have just posted a second answer about the three exponent case. Note that the comment from wdkrnls is consistent with my own answer only in the case $a=0$ and with minor difference in notations A,B,C.

Comment: @wdkrnls I suppose that your calculus is for the case where $a=0$. If $a\neq 0$ there should be a $x^3$ term in the integral equation. A cause of imaginary solutions to $p,q,r$ might be the inversion of $A=p+q+r$ and $C=pqr$.

Comment: @DrM. Hi ! Since I have not much practical results with the method given in my second answer, I should be interested to know if you tested it in some concret cases and your observations.

Comment: I studied the behaviors of the single and bi exponential solutions, on data that might have a third (or more) expionential term,  10 nsecs,  50 nsecs, and 2.8 msecs, so the last is well separated from the first two.  For the single exponent, I looked at fitting the tail, the answer varies wildly with how mych of the tail I use.   After settling on an offset, the bi exp seems okay for the second rate and third rate.   Still working on all of this though.

Comment: If I could communicate with you privately, I could send you some example data

Comment: I agree, it should be more efficient to communicate privately. But how exchange privately the e-mail adresses ?

Comment: your name is public, so that much is easy.  but, do you have a current affiliation?  or a publication list with author correspondence?

Comment: You could try on "Scrib" where several on my papers are published : http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents/ or on "Les-mathematiques.net" in the section "Messages privés" : http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/pm.php

Comment: @DrM. For information : The paper https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales is on the way to be translated. An incomplete version is available : https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendices/references.html  Presently the section "Double exponential regression" is not translated.

Comment: Hi Jean ! How are you doing in this terrible time ? Take care. Cheers.

Comment: @JJacquelin, is this solution same as yours? Feels similar, have been using it for some years for system identification of linear systems of the type dx/dt = A*x + B*u
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3805262/605948

Comment: @Juan Gonzalez Burgos. The basic principle appears the same except that, in the Wiki paper, the calculus is based on numerical differentiation instead of numerical integration. Note that the method based on differentials is proposed as well at the begining of the paper https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . As pointed out, numerical integrations are much more robust than differentiations in case of scatter. That is why the method of regression and integral equation is prefered on practical viewpoint.

Comment: That is also why in case of numerical calculus of differentials it is recommend applying a non-causal low pass filter first. But the final result will depend a lot on the kind of noise and the kind of filter. I guess that the results will be quite the same in case of low noise. It should be of interest to compare in practice the results from both methods in case of high noise.

Comment: @JJacquelin, understood. Is there a way to use linear algrebra to re-write your solution using integration, in order to have a numeric algorithm for n exponentials, as I did for my solution?

Comment: @Juan Gonzalez Burgos. Theoretically I say yes. This was done up to 3 exponentials. Of course this could be done for more exponentials. But the equations become more and more complicated and the number of adjustable parameters becomes more and more high, making the numerical calculus more and more subject to deviation due to the scatter of data. I guess this drawback is even more important with the method using differentials, which is somehow hiden by the apparent simplicity of the theory.

Comment: @JJacquelin, totally agree that a large n will give problems no matter the algorithm. But if we could put your integral solution in a general form for n exponentials, like in my derivative case, we would have both advantages of robustness agains noice, and agorithm simplicity. Just food for thought.Merci pour votre attention. BTW : I use the deirvative method in my project https://pidtuner.com with noisy industrial data with quite some success.

Comment: @Juan Gonzalez Burgos. I see your point and mainly agree. But in both cases the theories are quite similar. For me the question of scatter is more important. Personnally I prefer numerical integration instead of numerical differentiation requiring a filter process. Anyways, thank you for this interesting discussion.

Comment: @JJacquelin, this morning I took some time to re-derive the solution based on linear algebra but this time using integrals here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3808325/605948. I think looks even more to your solution, but generalized for n number of exponentials.

Comment: @JJacquelin, what if I want to fit to $y(x)=be^{px} + c^{qx}$, i.e. saving one degree of freedom by constraining $a$ to $0$?

Comment: @Yanqi Huang. The 5x5 matrix is reduced to a 4x4 matrix. This simplified case is edited in a new answer in addition to the preceeding answers.

Comment: @JJacquelin Thanks. That's exactly what I want. :)

Answer (score 9):

Edit: some people have asked me about the **license** of the code below. [The license is MIT as specified in this Github repository](https://github.com/juangburgos/FitSumExponentials).

---

I would like to add another solution, after the useful discussion with @JJacquelin. I reworked [my previous solution based on linear algebra and derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3805262/605948), to work with integrals instead. It also works for $n$ exponentials.

Assuming the data set $(y, x)$;

Compute the $n$ integrals of $y$ ; $\int y, \int^2{y}, \cdots , , \int^{n-1}{y} , \int^n{y}$.

Compute the $n-1$ powers of the independent variable $x$ ; $x, x^2, \cdots , x^{n-1}$.

Solve linear least squares problem for $[a_{1}, a_{2}, \cdots, a_{n-1}, a_{n}, k_{n-1}, k_{n-2} , \cdots , k_{2}, k_{1}, k_{0}]$ in:

$$
y = \left[ \int y , \int^2{y} , \cdots, \int^{n-1}{y}, \int^n{y} , x^{n-1}, x^{n-2}, \cdots , x^{2}, x, 1 \right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
a_{1} \\ a_{2} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n-1} \\ a_{n} \\ k_{n-1} \\ k_{n-2} \\ \vdots \\ k_{2} \\ k_{1} \\ k_{0}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
y = Y A \\
Y^T Y A = Y^T y \\
A = (Y^T Y)^{-1}Y^T y
$$

Then use the first $n$ elements of $A$ to form the transfer matrix of the integral equation:

$$
\bar{A} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_{n-1} & a_{n} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Compute the eigenvalues of $\bar{A}$ to obtain the solution of the characteristic polynomial.

The eigenvalues $\lambda _n$ are then the values of the exponentials in:

$$
y = 
p_1 e^{\lambda _1 x} + 
p_2 e^{\lambda _2 x} + 
\cdots + 
p_{n-1} e^{\lambda _{n-1} x} + 
p_n e^{\lambda _n x}
$$

To obtain the missing $p_n$, calculate numerically the exponential terms $e^{\lambda _n}$ and solve the least squares problem for $[p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_{n-1}, p_n ]$ in

$$
y = [e^{\lambda _1 x}, e^{\lambda _2 x} , \cdots, e^{\lambda _{n-1} x}, e^{\lambda _n x}]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
p_1 \\
p_2 \\
\vdots \\
p_{n-1} \\
p_n
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
y = X P \\
X^T X P = X^T y \\
P = (X^T X)^{-1}X^T y
$$

Now you have your $n$ exponential model parameters $p_n$ and $\lambda _n$.

This solution based on integrals, looks much more similar to @JJacquelin's solutions for cases $n = 2$ and $n = 3$, but now generalized for any $n$.

Here is the Python code for a test case with $n = 4$ (you can test it online [here](http://juangburgos.github.io/FitSumExponentials/)):

```
# Import PyArma
from pyarma import *

# Generate data to fit
dx = 0.02
x = regspace(dx, dx, 1.5)
y = 5*exp(0.5*x) + 4*exp(-3*x) + 2*exp(-2*x) - 3*exp(0.15*x)

# Compute integrals
def cumtrapz(x, y):
    return join_vert(mat(1,1), 0.5 * cumsum(diff(x) @ (y[1:y.n_elem-1,0] + y[0:y.n_elem-2,0])))

iy1 = cumtrapz(x, y)
iy2 = cumtrapz(x, iy1)
iy3 = cumtrapz(x, iy2)
iy4 = cumtrapz(x, iy3)

# Compute exponentials lambdas
def join_horizontal(*args):
    if type(args[0]) is tuple:
        args = args[0]
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    else:
        return join_horiz(args[0], join_horizontal(args[1:len(args)]))

Y = join_horizontal(iy1, iy2, iy3, iy4, pow(x, 3), pow(x, 2), x, ones(size(x)))
A = pinv(Y)*y;
lambdas = eig_gen(mat([
    [A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3]],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0]
]))[0]
lambdas = real(lambdas)
lambdas.print("lambdas = ")
#lambdas = 
#  -2.9991
#  -1.9997
#   0.5000
#   0.1500

# Compute exponentials multipliers
X = join_horizontal(exp(lambdas[0]*x), exp(lambdas[1]*x), exp(lambdas[2]*x), exp(lambdas[3]*x))
P = pinv(X)*y;
P.print("P = ")
#P = 
#   4.0042
#   1.9955
#   4.9998
#  -2.9996
```

### Variations

#### Additive constant term

If it is desired to fit a sum of exponentials plus constant $k$:

$$
y = 
k +
p_1 e^{\lambda _1 x} + 
p_2 e^{\lambda _2 x} + 
\cdots + 
p_{n-1} e^{\lambda _{n-1} x} + 
p_n e^{\lambda _n x}
$$

Just add $x^n$ to the first least squares problem and a constant to the second least squares problem:

```
# Import PyArma
from pyarma import *

# Generate data to fit
dx = 0.02
x = regspace(dx, dx, 1.5)
y = -1 + 5*exp(0.5*x) + 4*exp(-3*x) + 2*exp(-2*x)

# Compute integrals
def cumtrapz(x, y):
    return join_vert(mat(1,1), 0.5 * cumsum(diff(x) @ (y[1:y.n_elem-1,0] + y[0:y.n_elem-2,0])))

iy1 = cumtrapz(x, y)
iy2 = cumtrapz(x, iy1)
iy3 = cumtrapz(x, iy2)

# Compute exponentials lambdas
def join_horizontal(*args):
    if type(args[0]) is tuple:
        args = args[0]
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    else:
        return join_horiz(args[0], join_horizontal(args[1:len(args)]))

Y = join_horizontal(iy1, iy2, iy3, pow(x, 3), pow(x, 2), x, ones(size(x)))
A = pinv(Y)*y;
lambdas = eig_gen(mat([
    [A[0], A[1], A[2]],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0]
]))[0]
lambdas = real(lambdas)
lambdas.print("lambdas = ")
#lambdas = 
#  -2.9991
#  -1.9997
#   0.5000

# Compute exponentials multipliers
X = join_horizontal(ones(size(x)), exp(lambdas[0]*x), exp(lambdas[1]*x), exp(lambdas[2]*x))
P = pinv(X)*y;
P.print("P = ")
#P = 
#  -0.9996
#   4.0043
#   1.9955
#   4.9999
```

#### Sine and Cosine

If it is desired to fit a sum of exponentials plus a $cosine$ or a $sine$, the algorithm is exactly the same. Sines and cosines manifest themselves as a pair of complex conjugate eigen-values of $\hat{A}$.

For example, if we fit one exponential and one cosine:

```
# Import PyArma
from pyarma import *

# Generate data to fit
dx = 0.02
x = regspace(dx, dx, 1.5)
y = 5*exp(0.5*x) + 4*cos(0.15*x)

# Compute integrals
def cumtrapz(x, y):
    return join_vert(mat(1,1), 0.5 * cumsum(diff(x) @ (y[1:y.n_elem-1,0] + y[0:y.n_elem-2,0])))

iy1 = cumtrapz(x, y)
iy2 = cumtrapz(x, iy1)
iy3 = cumtrapz(x, iy2)

# Compute exponentials lambdas
def join_horizontal(*args):
    if type(args[0]) is tuple:
        args = args[0]
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    else:
        return join_horiz(args[0], join_horizontal(args[1:len(args)]))

Y = join_horizontal(iy1, iy2, iy3, pow(x, 2), x, ones(size(x)))
A = pinv(Y)*y;
lambdas = eig_gen(mat([
    [A[0], A[1], A[2]],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0]
]))[0]
lambdas.print("lambdas = ")
#lambdas = 
#    (+5.000e-01,+0.000e+00)
#    (+2.630e-10,+1.500e-01)
#    (+2.630e-10,-1.500e-01)

# Compute exponentials multipliers
x = cx_mat(x)
X = join_horizontal(exp(lambdas[0]*x), exp(lambdas[1]*x), exp(lambdas[2]*x))
P = pinv(X)*y;
P.print("P = ")
#P = 
#    (+5.000e+00,-4.376e-15)
#    (+2.000e+00,+9.206e-05)
#    (+2.000e+00,-9.206e-05)
```

Note the cosine multiplier $4$ appears in $P$ as $2$ times $2$.

If we were to fit a $sine$ instead we would get:

```
y = 5*exp(0.5*x) + 4*sin(0.15*x)

#lambdas = 
#    (+5.000e-01,+0.000e+00)
#    (+7.357e-11,+1.500e-01)
#    (+7.357e-11,-1.500e-01)

#P = 
#    (+5.000e+00,-1.504e-14)
#    (-4.654e-05,-2.000e+00)
#    (-4.654e-05,+2.000e+00)
```

Note now the $2$ times $2$ appears in the complex part of $P$.

#### Exponential multiplied by $x$

If it is desired to fit a sum of exponentials, some with repeated $\lambda$ but multiplied by $x$, again the exact same method can be used. This scenario manifest itself as repeated eigen-values of $\hat{A}$:

```
# Import PyArma
from pyarma import *

# Generate data to fit
dx = 0.02
x = regspace(dx, dx, 1.5)
y = 5*exp(0.5*x) + 4*exp(-3*x) + 2*x@exp(-3*x)

# Compute integrals
def cumtrapz(x, y):
    return join_vert(mat(1,1), 0.5 * cumsum(diff(x) @ (y[1:y.n_elem-1,0] + y[0:y.n_elem-2,0])))

iy1 = cumtrapz(x, y)
iy2 = cumtrapz(x, iy1)
iy3 = cumtrapz(x, iy2)

# Compute exponentials lambdas
def join_horizontal(*args):
    if type(args[0]) is tuple:
        args = args[0]
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    else:
        return join_horiz(args[0], join_horizontal(args[1:len(args)]))

Y = join_horizontal(iy1, iy2, iy3, pow(x, 2), x, ones(size(x)))
A = pinv(Y)*y;
lambdas = eig_gen(mat([
    [A[0], A[1], A[2]],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0]
]))[0]
lambdas = real(lambdas)
lambdas.print("lambdas = ")
#lambdas = 
#  -2.9991
#  -2.9991 NOTE : repeated means x*exp(lambda*x)
#   0.5000

# Compute exponentials multipliers
#P = 
#   4.0001
#   1.9955
#   5.0000
```

### What if I don't know how many exponentials fit my data?

If the structure of the model to fit is unknown, one can simply run the algorithm for a large $n$ and compute the singular values of $Y$. By looking at the singular values, we can infer how many of them are actually needed to fit most of the data. From this we can select a minimum $n$ and based in the singular values of $\hat{A}$ we can also deduce the structure of the model (how many exponentials, sines, cosines, if there are exponentials multiplied times $x$, etc.).

```
# Import PyArma
from pyarma import *

# Generate data to fit
dx = 0.02
x = regspace(dx, dx, 1.5)
y = 5*exp(0.5*x) + 4*exp(-3*x) + 2*exp(-2*x)

# Compute N integrals of y and N-1 powers of x
def cumtrapz(x, y):
    return join_vert(mat(1,1), 0.5 * cumsum(diff(x) @ (y[1:y.n_elem-1,0] + y[0:y.n_elem-2,0])))

n = 10
iy = zeros(x.n_elem, n)
xp = zeros(x.n_elem, n-1)
iy[:,0] = cumtrapz(x, y)
xp[:,0] = ones(size(x))
for ii in range(1, n-1):
    iy[:, ii] = cumtrapz(x, iy[:, ii-1])
    xp[:, ii] = xp[:, ii-1] @ x
iy[:, n-1] = cumtrapz(x, iy[:, n-2])

# Compute Singular Values of Y
def join_horizontal(*args):
    if type(args[0]) is tuple:
        args = args[0]
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    else:
        return join_horiz(args[0], join_horizontal(args[1:len(args)]))

Y = join_horizontal(iy, xp)
ysv = svd(Y)[1]

# Scale Singular Values to Percentage
ysv_scaled = (100/sum(ysv)[0,0]) * ysv
ysv_scaled.print("ysv_scaled = ")
#ysv_scaled = 
#   6.9014e+01
#   2.4043e+01
#   4.5012e+00
#   1.6753e+00
#   6.4420e-01
#   1.0649e-01
#   ...value lower than 1.4482e-02

# Select the N Principal Components
thres = 0.1
n_ysv_scaled = mat(ysv_scaled[ find(ysv_scaled > thres) ])
N = n_ysv_scaled.n_elem / 2
print(N)
# 3
covers = sum(n_ysv_scaled)
covers.print("covers = ")
#covers = 
#   99.9840
# Covers 99.9% of all components contributions
```

Comment: Bravo ! Smart theoretical work. Nevertheless, in practical applications I am afraid that successive numerical integrations will give more and more inconsistant results. But this is much better than succesive numerical differentiations due to the noise.

Comment: Note : To be more complet the function to fit should be the sum of $n$ exponentials plus one unknown constant. But this doesn't change the method. Only a few changes in the linear algorithm. Best regards.

Comment: Yes, just added it. Actually the method works for sines, cosines, and exponentials multiplied by powers of $x$. It depends on the eigenvalues of $\hat{A}$, I just don't have the time to put up all variations. Actually by analyzing the principal components  (singular value decomposition) of $Y^T Y$ with a large $n = m$ where $m >> n$  we could infer how many exponentials are needed to get a useful fit with minimum $n$.

Comment: Very well. The method works for many other functions: Weibull, logistic, gaussian,  mixed polynomial and sinusoidal, etc. A lot of examples are shown in the paper 
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales .

Comment: Mon francais ne marche pas tres bien, mais je vais essayer!

Comment: An English version of the paper published on Scribd is on the way to be translated (far from finished) :
https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendices/references.html

Comment: I read your paper, now I am convinced that the approach is the same. The difference being that you compute every case manually, while the linear algebra gives a general solution for sum of $n$ exponentials.But the real power of the linear algebra approach, is that we don't need to know how many exponentials we need in advance, because we can infer that from the data. The singular value decomposition of $Y$ tells us what $n$ we should use to fit the data, and the eigen-values of $\hat{A}$ tells us if the data contains sines, cosines or exponentials multiplied by powers of $x$.

Comment: I didn't come up with all this my myself. There are standard results of system theory for an even more general case. The fit we treat here is what is called the "free response" of a system in derivative form $\dot{x} = Ax$. The more general case contains also a "forced response" $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$.

Comment: I added more variations and a sketch on how to deduce $n$ from data.

Comment: @JuanGonzalezBurgos. Very interesting discussion !

Comment: @JJacquelin. Very interesting discussion  Cheers, Jean !

Comment: I believe computing this fit of N exponentials is a generalization of the Fourier series in a similar way as the Laplace transform generalizes the Fourier transform, because it not only contains sines and cosines, but also decaying and growing exponentials. So maybe this would be some kind of "Laplace series" of the signal $x$, $y$?

Answer (score 5):

In response to questions raised in comments about the three exponents case, the method of regression based on integral equation is roughly explain below, with a numerical example.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Always impressive !

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Hi Claude ! Thank you for the compliment and for your interest in this subject.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Will try it shortly.

Comment: Aside,  I am looking into transforms that provide the rate constants as poles.  There is the Pady-Laplace of course.   The fourier transform of  x e^{-r x} and variations, seem interesting also.   Have you worked with methods of that sort?  What are your thoughts?  Thank you

Comment: Ojne of the physically most interesting questions in a large class of problems, is how many exponential rates are there?    It is about how many states are there in the system, to which the number of rates is the answer.

Comment: @DRM. Sure those topics are of interest. But I am not specialist in this field.

Comment: Jean,  I have python implementations for the two exponent, and three exponent cases.   I want to ask your permission first, before I post them here.   Your detailed printout was extremely helpful in checking the implementation.  Of interest perhaps, the errors in the python implementation are larger than in yours. I think to follow it with a round of LSQ, perhaps only on the coeffs and rates.

Comment: P/S Where are you now?   I only find an old affiliation for you at researchgate.

Comment: There is no need for permission. I am retired and there is no property rignt for the industrial company where I wrorked a long time ago. It should be interesting to find what is the cause of the difference between  your results with Python and my own results with an homemade software (built with Delphi). The numerical result in the simplified case of non-scattered data shown in my above answer where checked with mathcad. But don't be surprised by much larger errors and deviation in cases of scattered data.

Comment: It was your credit for working it out that I was thinking of.  But, any, I posted the code here as a new answer.   Your paper on electrodes with a capacitive layer is relevant to my research, very interesting.  I look forward to reading it.

Comment: What is your research? In field of electrochemistry ? Complex analysis ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didnt see your comment.   I am working in OLEDS, one of the important problems is charge injection from a metal electrode to a dielectric.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients).

If we want to fit to n exponentials, follow the steps:

Calculate $n$ derivatives of $y$ ; $y^{(n)}, y^{(n-1)}, \cdots , \ddot y , \dot y , y$

Solve linear least squares problem for $[-a_{n-1}, \cdots, -a_2, -a_1, -a_0 ]$ in

$$
y^{(n)} = [y^{(n-1)} , \cdots, \ddot y, \dot y, y]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
-a_{n-1} \\
\vdots \\
-a_2 \\
-a_1 \\
-a_0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
y^{(n)} = Y A \\
Y^T Y A = Y^T y^{(n)} \\
A = (Y^T Y)^{-1}Y^T y^{(n)}
$$

Obtain the roots of the characteristic polynomial (using Matlab roots or similar):

$$
z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_2 z^2 + a_1z + a_0
$$

The roots $\lambda _n$ are then the values of the exponentials in

$$
y = 
p_1 e^{\lambda _1 x} + 
p_2 e^{\lambda _2 x} + 
\cdots + 
p_{n-1} e^{\lambda _{n-1} x} + 
p_n e^{\lambda _n x}
$$

To obtain the missing $p_n$, calculate numerically the exponential terms $e^{\lambda _n}$ and solve the least squares problem for $[p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_{n-1}, p_n ]$ in

$$
y = [e^{\lambda _1 x}, e^{\lambda _2 x} , \cdots, e^{\lambda _{n-1} x}, e^{\lambda _n x}]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
p_1 \\
p_2 \\
\vdots \\
p_{n-1} \\
p_n
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
y = X P \\
X^T X P = X^T y \\
P = (X^T X)^{-1}X^T y
$$

Now you have your $n$ exponential model parameters $p_n$ and $\lambda _n$.

I believe this approach is similar of not the same as the one proposed by @JJacquelin, but you have a generic algorithm for $n$ exponentials.

If your $y$ data is noise, I would recommend applying a non-causal low pass filter first.

Here is the Matlab code (you can test it online [here](https://octave-online.net/bucket%7EEsk79YnMSzr2PiyWE6nzWd)):

```
clear all;
clc;
% get data
dx = 0.01;
x  = (dx:dx:1.5)';
y  =  5*exp(0.5*x) + 4*exp(-3*x) + 2*exp(-2*x);
% calculate derivatives
dy1 = diff(y)/dx;
dy2 = diff(dy1)/dx;
dy3 = diff(dy2)/dx;
% fix derivatives lengths
dy1 = [dy1(1)-(dy1(2)-dy1(1)); dy1];
dy2 = [dy2(1)-2*(dy2(2)-dy2(1)); dy2(1)- (dy2(2)-dy2(1)); dy2];
dy3 = [dy3(1)-3*(dy3(2)-dy3(1)); dy3(1)-2*(dy3(2)-dy3(1)); dy3(1)- (dy3(2)-dy3(1)); dy3];
% get exponentials lambdas
Y = [dy2, dy1, y];
A = pinv(Y)*dy3;
lambdas = roots([1; -A]);
lambdas
%lambdas =
%  -3.0336
%  -1.9933
%   0.4989
% get exponentials multipliers
X = [exp(lambdas(1)*x), exp(lambdas(2)*x), exp(lambdas(3)*x)];
P = pinv(X)*y;
P
%P =
%   3.9461
%   2.0514
%   5.0067
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is are implementations of the two and three exponent cases, from Jean Jacquelin's work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

'''
Implementation of two and three exponent cases from Jean Jacquelin's
REGRESSION et EQUATION INTEGRALE, available at
https://www.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales
'''    

__author__    = "M Nelson"
__date__      = "January 19, 2020"
__version__   = "0.1"


import sys
import argparse

import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
from scipy.linalg import lstsq
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def biexpfit( xdata, ydata, debug=False ):

    x = np.array(xdata)
    y = np.array(ydata)
    if debug:
        print( 'x', x )
        print( 'y', y )

    S = np.empty_like(y)
    S[0] = 0
    S[1:] = np.cumsum(0.5 * (y[1:] + y[:-1]) * np.diff(x))
    if debug:
        print('S', S )

    SS = np.empty_like(y)
    SS[0] = 0
    SS[1:] = np.cumsum(0.5 * (S[1:] + S[:-1]) * np.diff(x))
    if debug:
        print('SS', SS )

    x2 = x * x
    x3 = x2 * x
    x4 = x2 * x2

    M = [ [sum(SS*SS),  sum(SS*S), sum( SS*x2 ), sum(SS*x), sum(SS)],
          [sum(SS*S),   sum(S*S),  sum(S*x2),    sum(S*x), sum(S) ],
          [sum(SS*x2),  sum(S*x2), sum(x4),      sum(x3),  sum(x2) ],
          [sum(SS*x),   sum(S*x),  sum(x3),      sum(x2),  sum(x) ],
          [sum(SS),     sum(S),    sum(x2),      sum(x),   len(xdata) ] ]

    if debug:
        print( 'M' )
        for n in range(5):
            print( M[n] )

    Ycol = np.array( [ sum(SS*y), sum(S*y), sum(x2*y), sum(x*y), sum(y) ] )

    (A,B,C,D,E),residues,rank,singulars = list( lstsq( M, Ycol ) )
    if debug:
        print( 'A-E', A, B, C, D, E )

    '''
    Minv = np.linalg.inv(M)    
    A,B,C,D,E = list( np.matmul(Minv,Ycol) )
    '''

    p = (1/2.)*(B + sqrt(B*B+4*A))
    q = (1/2.)*(B - sqrt(B*B+4*A))
    if debug:
        print( 'p,q', p, q )

    beta = np.exp(p*x)
    eta = np.exp(q*x)

    betaeta = beta * eta

    L = [ [ len(xdata), sum(beta), sum(eta) ],
          [ sum(beta),  sum(beta*beta), sum(betaeta) ],
          [ sum(eta),   sum(betaeta), sum(eta*eta)] ]

    Ycol = np.array( [ sum(y), sum(beta*y), sum(eta*y) ] )

    (a,b,c),residues,rank,singulars = list( lstsq( L, Ycol ) )    
    if debug:
        print( 'a,b,c', a,b,c )

    '''
    Linv = np.linalg.inv(L)
    a,b,c = list( np.matmul( Linv, Ycol ) )
    '''

    # sort in ascending order (fastest negative rate first)
    (b,p),(c,q) = sorted( [[b,p],[c,q]], key=lambda x: x[1])

    return a,b,c,p,q


def triexpfit( xdata, ydata, debug=False ):

    x = np.array(xdata)
    y = np.array(ydata)
    if debug:
        print( 'x', x )
        print( 'y', y )

    S = np.empty_like(y)
    S[0] = 0
    S[1:] = np.cumsum(0.5 * (y[1:] + y[:-1]) * np.diff(x))
    if debug:
        print('S', S )

    SS = np.empty_like(y)
    SS[0] = 0
    SS[1:] = np.cumsum(0.5 * (S[1:] + S[:-1]) * np.diff(x))
    if debug:
        print('SS', SS )

    SSS = np.empty_like(y)
    SSS[0] = 0
    SSS[1:] = np.cumsum(0.5 * (SS[1:] + SS[:-1]) * np.diff(x))
    if debug:
        print('SSS', SSS )

    x2 = x * x
    x3 = x2 * x
    x4 = x3 * x
    x5 = x4 * x
    x6 = x5 * x

    M = [ [ sum(SSS*SSS), sum(SSS*SS), sum(SSS*S), sum(SSS*x3), sum(SSS*x2), sum(SSS*x), sum(SSS) ],
          [ sum(SSS*SS), sum(SS*SS), sum(SS*S), sum(SS*x3), sum(SS*x2), sum(SS*x), sum(SS) ],
          [ sum(SSS*S), sum(SS*S), sum(S*S), sum(S*x3), sum(S*x2), sum(S*x), sum(S) ],
          [ sum(SSS*x3), sum(SS*x3), sum(S*x3), sum(x6), sum(x5), sum(x4), sum(x3) ],
          [ sum(SSS*x2), sum(SS*x2), sum(S*x2), sum(x5), sum(x4), sum(x3), sum(x2) ],
          [ sum(SSS*x), sum(SS*x), sum(S*x), sum(x4), sum(x3), sum(x2), sum(x) ],
          [ sum(SSS), sum(SS), sum(S), sum(x3), sum(x2), sum(x), len(xdata) ] ]

    if debug:
        print( 'M' )
        for n in range(7):
            print( M[n] )

    Ycol = [ sum(y*SSS), sum(y*SS), sum(y*S), sum(y*x3), sum(y*x2), sum(y*x), sum(y) ]

    if debug:
        print( 'Y', Ycol )

    '''
    Minv = np.linalg.inv(M)
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G = list( np.matmul( Minv, Ycol ) )
    print( 'A-G linalg', A, B, C, D, E, F, G )
    '''

    (A,B,C,D,E,F,G),residues,rank,singulars = list( lstsq( M, Ycol ) )
    if debug:
        print( 'A-G', A, B, C, D, E, F, G )

    p,q,r = np.roots( [1.,-C,-B,-A] )
    p,q,r = sorted( [p,q,r] )
    if debug:
        print( 'p,q,r', p, q, r )

    L = [ [ len(xdata), sum(np.exp(p*x)),sum(np.exp(q*x)),sum(np.exp(r*x)) ],
          [ sum(np.exp(p*x)), sum(np.exp(2*p*x)),sum(np.exp((p+q)*x)),sum(np.exp((p+r)*x)) ],
          [ sum(np.exp(q*x)), sum(np.exp((p+q)*x)),sum(np.exp(2*q*x)),sum(np.exp((q+r)*x)) ],
          [ sum(np.exp(r*x)), sum(np.exp((p+r)*x)),sum(np.exp((q+r)*x)),sum(np.exp(2*r*x)) ] ]

    Ycol = [ sum(y), sum(y*np.exp(p*x)),sum(y*np.exp(q*x)),sum(y*np.exp(r*x)) ]

    (a,b,c,d),residues,rank,singulars = list( lstsq( L, Ycol ) )
    if debug:
        print( 'a,b,c,d', a,b,c,d )


    # sort in ascending order (fastest negative rate first)
    (b,p),(c,q),(d,r) = sorted( [[b,p],[c,q],[d,r]], key=lambda x: x[1])

    return a,b,c,d, p,q,r


def __regression_tests__(debug=False):

    x = np.linspace( 0, 2., 100 )

    a, b = 1., 2.
    p = -5.
    print( 'inputs', a, b, p )

    y = a + b * np.exp( p*x )

    a, b, p = expfit( x, y )
    print( 'fits', a, b, p )

    a, b, c = 1.0, .5, 0.25
    p,q = -10., -5.
    print( 'inputs', a,b,c,p,q )

    y = a + b * np.exp( p*x ) + c * np.exp( q* x )

    a,b,c,p,q =  biexpfit( x, y )
    print( 'fits', a,b,c,p,q )


    a, b, c, d = -1., 5., 4., 2.
    p, q, r = .5, -3., -2.
    print( 'inputs', a,b,c,d, p,q,r )

    x = np.linspace( .1, 1.5, 15 )
    print( x )    

    y = a + b * np.exp( p*x ) + c * np.exp( q* x ) + d * np.exp( r* x )
    print( y )

    a,b,c,d, p,q,r = triexpfit( x, y, debug )
    print( 'fits', a,b,c,d, p,q,r )
```

Comment: Wow, amazing work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KenGrimes  Thank you, but really this is Jean's solution.  I just coded it.   Also helpful were comments from another contributor.  A caveat to note is that while the 2 term case is pretty good, and especially useful for the baseline, the 3 term case is not always better than the usual minimization methods.

Answer (score 2):

In order to answer to the comment from Yanqi Huang the method of fitting
$$y=be^{px}+ce^{qx}$$
is shown below. This is the same as in the first answer but with one line and column suppressed related to the suppression of the parameter $a$. There is no longer $a\:x^2$ in the linear integral equation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fall on your discussion while looking at how to fit Weibull distribution (PDF or CDF). 
As you may know, these days we look at many exponentials curves which commonly result in the sum of local exponentials. I am no expert but I was giving it a try. 
I try solving a sum of Weibull distributions (which gives exponentials when the shape parameter equals one). 
I did not find immediately a minimizing solution, so I was just looking to your method in case.
And because a few equations are worth many words:

[image]

If any idea or suggestion, gladly appreciated :)

In all cases, thanks so much for this post. I guess I will spend the day implementing your approach.