# Fit sum of exponentials - excluding intercept

Tags: optimization, algorithms, exponential-function

**Question**

 Given data points,
$$(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ..., (x_n, y_n)$$
Suppose I know
$$y_i\sim\mathrm{Laplace}(f(x_i),\sigma)$$
Where
$$f(x)=be^{px} + c^{qx}$$
For some $b, c, p, q, \sigma > 0\in\mathbb{R}$.
Here, by MLE, instead of optimizing the MSE, i.e. $\Sigma_i{(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2}$, we want to optimize the absolute diviation, i.e. $\Sigma_i{|y_i-\hat{y}_i|}$.

 **However, answers optimizing the MSE, i.e. $\Sigma_i{(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2}$ will also be accepted**.

 **Linkage with Other Answered**

Luckily, we have a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1428566/758170). The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1428659/758170) claims that it optimizes the absolute deviance, which I deem to be MSE. However, this time, I want to fit to
$$y(x)=be^{px} + c^{qx}$$
Instead of $$y(x)=a + be^{px} + c^{qx}$$.
That is to say, I want to save one degree of freedom by constraining $a$ to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your special case seems to be covered by [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3808325/605948) from the question you mention.