# Fit sum of multivariate exponentials

Tags: algorithms, exponential-function

I am working on a curve fitting task for a function which is multivariate sum of two exponentials.
The function which I am trying to fit has below form:
$$z(x,y)=ae^{bx}y+ce^{dx}$$
and want to find a, b, c, d values given values of x, y and z from measurement data.
Has anyone already worked on such function?
It seems not possible to linearize the problem using function integrals as done for fitting of sum of exponentials with single variable because second variable y is present in only one exponential term.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Could you please give a reference for the "linearize the problem using function integrals as done for fitting of sum of exponentials...", so we know what is the approach?

Comment: @Juan Gonzalez Burgos. A reference :  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution exactly at 4:20. Your specific case is a lucky one because the term that depends on the independent variable $y$ affects linearly the non-linear exponentials that depend on $x$. So the problem remains linear and you can still apply [the method I proposed in this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3808325/605948) (with some minor changes).

First you have to store your data $z(x,y)$ in a (tall) column vector, putting each $y$ sample head-to-tail with each other. Assuming you have $nx$ number of samples in $x$, and $ny$ number of samples in $y$:

$$
z = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
z(x, y_1) \\
z(x, y_2) \\
\vdots \\
z(x, y_{ny})
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Now we need to equate the right hand side of the equation according to the proposed method. For all $ny$ samples in $y$, the exponental terms ("lambdas") are the same, but the terms that multiply $x$ and the constant are not, so the matrix should have the form:

$$
Z = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
\int{z(x, y_1)} & \int^2{z(x, y_1)} & x & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
\int{z(x, y_2)} & \int^2{z(x, y_2)} & 0 & 0 & x & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots \\
\int{z(x, y_{ny})} & \int^2{z(x, y_{ny})} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & x & 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

So now we have:

$$
z = Z A
$$

So:

$$
A = (Z^T Z)^{-1}Z^T z 
$$

$$
\lambda = eig\left(
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A(1) & A(2) \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\right) 
$$

The rest follows by the proposed method. The respective Python code is:

```
# Import PyArma
from pyarma import *

# Generate data to fit
# Independent variable x
dx = 0.02
x = regspace(dx, dx, 1.5)
nx = x.n_elem
# Independent variable y
dy = 0.05
y = regspace(dy, dy, 1.5)
ny = y.n_elem
# Dependent variable z(x,y)
# Stored in column vector head-to-tail for each y[k]
z = zeros(nx*ny, 1)
for k in range(0, ny):
    z_start = nx*k
    z_end   = nx*(k+1)-1
    z[z_start:z_end,:] = 5*exp(0.5*x)*y[k] + 4*exp(-3*x)

# Compute exponentials lambdas
def cumtrapz(x, y):
    return join_vert(mat(1,1), 0.5 * cumsum(diff(x) @ (y[1:y.n_elem-1,0] + y[0:y.n_elem-2,0])))

def join_horizontal(*args):
    if type(args[0]) is tuple:
        args = args[0]
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    else:
        return join_horiz(args[0], join_horizontal(args[1:len(args)]))
# Build least squares matrix Z to obtain the lambdas
Z = zeros(nx*ny, 2+2*ny)
for k in range(0, ny):
    z_start = nx*k
    z_end   = nx*(k+1)-1
    # calculate integrals of z(y[k]) wrt x, for each kth sample in y
    iz1 = cumtrapz(x, z[z_start:z_end,:])
    iz2 = cumtrapz(x, iz1)
    # store in appropriate location
    Z[z_start:z_end, 0:1] = join_horizontal(iz1, iz2)
    Z[z_start:z_end, 2+2*k:3+2*k] = join_horizontal(x, ones(size(x)))
# Solve the least squares and eigenvalue problems
A = pinv(Z)*z
lambdas = eig_gen(mat([
    [A[0], A[1]],
    [1, 0]
]))[0]
lambdas = real(lambdas)
lambdas.print("lambdas = ")
#lambdas = 
#  -2.9991
#   0.5000

# Compute exponentials multipliers
# Build least squares matrix X and solve the least squares problem to obtain the multipliers
X = zeros(nx*ny, 2)
for k in range(0, ny):
    x_start = nx*k
    x_end   = nx*(k+1)-1
    X[x_start:x_end, :] = join_horizontal(exp(lambdas[1]*x)*y[k], exp(lambdas[0]*x))
# solve the least squares problem
P = pinv(X)*z;
P = real(P)
P.print("P = ")
#P = 
#   4.9999
#   3.9995
```

You can try it online here:

http://juangburgos.github.io/FitSumExponentials/

Please upvote [my proposed method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3808325/605948) in the other question if you found it useful.

---

Edit:

@PayasVartak, the lambdas computation using the eigenvalues is indeed the optimal solution for the two lambdas (there only two values). The reason why you you might not be getting the best fit, might be because of the second least squares problem, in the "Estimate exponentials multipliers" section of the code.

Note that I used the equation:

```
join_horizontal( exp(lambdas[1]*x)*y[k], exp(lambdas[0]*x) )
```

for the fit, because I already knew in advance which exponential gets multiplied by y(k). But actually we don't know at this point which of the two exp(lambda(?)*x) is the one that gets multiplied by y(k). So actually you need to try also:

```
join_horizontal( exp(lambdas[1]*x), exp(lambdas[0]*x)*y[k] )
```

And see which one makes the best fit.

As @JJacquelin proposed, it might be a good idea to post some of your experimental data so we can help you better.

Comment: @ Juan: Thanks a lot for generous help.
I am observing a problem with this method as explained below.
After linearization, 
$$ (, )=_1 ∫(,_1 )+_2 ∬(,_1 )+_{11} x+_{10}+…+_1 ∫(,_ )+_2 ∬(,_ )+_{1} x+_{0} $$
Where,
$$P_1 = −_1−_2$$ and
$$P_2 = −_1_2$$
When solved for b1 and b2, we get two values for b1 and b2 each.  
$$_2=(−_1 ± √(_1^2+4_2 ))/2$$
Where as
$$ λ= eig(\begin{bmatrix}A(1) & A(2)\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix})$$
provides only one pair of values for b1 and b2; which is not always giving the best fit.

Comment: Thanks again for the edit. What you described in the edit was the same problem I was facing before.

Comment: Remember that A(1) and A(2) are the first two entries of the solution of the least squares problem A = inv(Z)*z. Then the lambdas are eigenvalues of the matrix formed using A(1) and A(2). So you cannot use P1 and P2 directly to get the lambdas, first you need to solve the least squares, then form the matrix, then obtain the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

The method of using integral equation to linearize the problem is explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . The case of two exponentials is treated pp.71-74. More exponentials are possible as well.

But the theory is done only in case of one variable.

In this paper the case of two variables is passed over superficially.pp.75-80. It is shown that the method can be extended in case of two variables if the data has a specific structure as shown in the numerical example pp.81-84 .

The case of $z(x,y)=ae^{bx}y+ce^{dx}$ is not explicitly treated. This would need more studies. The structure of the data (How the experimental points are presented in a table) is very important in practical application. In order to give a preliminary  advice on the feasibility in your case, you should joint to your question an example of data.

Comment: Hi Jean ! I was waiting for you here ! By the way, *Happy New Year !*. Cheers :-)

Comment: @)Claude Leibovici! Hi Claude ! All the best and good health in this new year !